# mysql Master-Master Replication or drdb heartbeat

Tags: mysql, database, performance, heartbeat, drbd

Im db replication newbie.

Im planing to add replication and failover features to our database system.

I have read toons of docs talking about scale-out or scale-in db systems and im a bit confused.

Currently i have only one data base stored in one server, And im planning to duplicate it in other new server.

I think that there are two solutions.

First one its to create a master-master replication and deal with the load balancer to manage the failover.

And the second one is to create an DRBD with heartbeat, with active-pasive database, creating a slave pointing to heartbeat virtual IP.

I looks that first solution will be easier than the second, but i want to know your opinion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, go with the master-master replication and using load balancing is the best option but it always depends over which type of applications you're using over.

while if you want to make a log of the users at that time creating virtual IP is the nice option.

Hope this information will help you on further development.

Comment: Thanks! for the info. I`ll use mysql Connector/J as load balacer.